# Importing .txt file and saving it in to class

Tags: java, arrays, import

I'm trying to import the values stored in .txt file and store it in a class using array.
But I can't do that I'm getting ArrayIndexoutofboundException1 error. 
Could you please help me with it.

My text file is like this

# See all Texts
# something here
91220   Figueroa & Exposition   213-749-9302
91220   Figueroa & Exposition   213-749-9302
91220   Figueroa & Exposition   213-749-9302
91220   Figueroa & Exposition   213-749-9302

And I have a class called prereqclass
Here is my code

if ( context.getAttribute("Preqattr") == null )

{

```
    ArrayList<prereqclass> prereqcl = new ArrayList<prereqclass>();
        String file = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "download.txt";
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
             if (line.trim().startsWith("#")) {
                    // do nothing
                 System.out.println("Entering # loop");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Entering the lines");
               String[] tokens = line.split("/t");
                 prereqcl.add(new prereqclass(tokens[0].trim(),tokens[1].trim(),tokens[2].trim() ) );
                 System.out.println("Attempt Success");
               for (String token : tokens)
                    System.out.println("\t" + token.replace('"', ' ').trim() );

                System.out.println("-------------------");

               }

               }

                br.close();

            context.setAttribute("Preqattr", prereqcl);
               }


               catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

this is the error
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at prereq.prereqserv.init(prereqserv.java:64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
String[] tokens = line.split("/t");
```

is presumably trying to split a tab-separated line, but you are using a forward-slash instead of a back-slash. It should be:

```
String[] tokens = line.split("\t");
```

You should check the length of `tokens` before attempting to index it, to help catch these types of errors. Even with the above change, if you encounter a line which isn't tab-separated for any reason, you will get the same exception. I would suggest wrapping the code where you access your `tokens` array with a length check:

```
if (tokens.length >= 3) {
    prereqcl.add(new prereqclass(tokens[0].trim(),tokens[1].trim(),tokens[2].trim() ) );
}
else {
    System.out.println("Only found " + tokens.length + " tokens.");
}
```

Comment: and how can I split it if the texts are separated with comma "," ex:CS120,Introduction to Web Site Development

Comment: The `split("\t")` can be reused for splitting by any other character. I'll leave the details for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to solve this type of problem is to step through your code line by line. Set a breakpoint where the error is, and then look at each variable and decide if the variable is what it is supposed to be. If it is not, then try stepping through the code again to see how the variable got in to the bad state.

Just as a hint I'm guessing that tokens doesn't have as many items in it as you think it should. You should check to see why that is.